# Facebook connect unique secret user identifier

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to let users login to my site using Facebook and I want to obtain a token from FB when the following properties:

1. For a given user, the token is always the same when they log in with facebok
2. The token is unique to my app.  That is if that user logs into some other app with facebook they aren't given the same token.

Does FB provide anything like this?  As far as I can tell the user id that the facebook api returns is the same for all applications.

I know that I could achieve #2 by sending the FB userID up to a server and hashing it with some secret key but I'm trying to make a purely client side application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provides a field `third_party_id` (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), that is unique to your app.

It’s main purpose is to be used to identify a user without violating their privacy, f.e. when you would have to pass a user id around as a parameter in a public URL or something.

If you ever need to “translate it back”, you can use it to look the user up via the [FQL user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) (with an access token for your app only, of course).